# Read .csv file with arbitrary spaces between entries

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-science

I have a `.csv` file for to read with `pd.read_csv()`. Unfortunately, each line is entered in a single cell instead of multiple cells for each column as shown below:

[image]

**I am trying something like this to read that file**:

```
sheffield = pd.read_csv('data/sheffield_weather_station.csv', skiprows=8, delimiter='|', engine='python')
```

It gives me this output without separating each value/data. I checked the spaces between columns in the Microsoft Excel, they are arbitrary. Is there a specific option of `pd.read_csv()` to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your values are not delimited by `|`. Try `sheffield = pd.read_csv('data/sheffield_weather_station.csv', skiprows=8, sep='\s+', engine='python')`

Comment: you can try adding delim_whitespace=True to see if that helps

Comment: This solved my problem. Never thought it would work. If you could write it as a response, so I can check it as solved. Best.

Comment: @oppressionslayer 's solution as `delim_whitespace=True`

Comment: Thanks @Jan. Your solution does also work perfect.

Comment: I upvoted you for thinking about me and Jan too, thx. :-) Jan's answer is great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try

```
sheffield = pd.read_csv('data/sheffield_weather_station.csv', skiprows=8, sep='\s+', engine='python')
```

It is essentially the same as `delim_whitespace=True` as it is an alias for the `sep` parameter, see the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on the matter.